# Obtain data from one time to another

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a data with UNIX time epoch. I am trying to separate only the data that falls in particular time range.

For Example: The full data between 8.00 AM to 8.00 PM only. i.e all the data that fall between and including the time range.

Any suggestions how  to start about please. I know this is not a code providing service. I am really clue less how to start with this kind of separation. The time zone to be considered is UTC +8.00.

```
Input data: col[2] col[3] are the start time and stop time respectively.

11048 10386 1171753215 1171753234 19 
83987 85230 1171753213 1171753234 21 
83987 86390 1171753213 1171753236 23 
6574 12027 1171753212 1171753233 21 
10788 40054 1171753217 1171753236 19 
70178 6574 1171753209 1171753229 20 
85241 87329 1171753205 1171753233 28 
81532 88962 1171753208 1171753231 23 
85271 82494 1171753213 1171753234 21 
2210 6774 1171753210 1171753234 24 
87563 11146 1171753203 1171753226 23 
87563 84877 1171753203 1171753228 25 
87563 40000 1171753203 1171753229 26
```

I need to separate the data of *col[2]* and *col[3]* that falls in particular time range. The time range should be able to be changed when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to compare datetime objects as  `t1.hour >= 8 and t2.hour <= 20` will return True for 20.01 etc.

```
from datetime import datetime,time

s = "11048 10386 11717532234 1171753234 19"

start = time(8, 0, 0) # start 8:00:00 am
end = time(20, 0, 0) # end 8:00:00 pm
spl = s.split() # split line 

# convert col 2 and 3 to datetime objects
t1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(spl[2])).time()
t2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(spl[3])).time()

print(t1 >= start and t2 <= end)
```

To extract the data to a file:

```
from datetime import datetime,time

start = time(8, 0, 0)
end = time(20, 0, 0)
with open("input.txt") as f,open("output.txt","w") as f1:
    for line in f:
        spl = line.split()
        t1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(spl[2])).time()
        t2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(spl[3])).time()
        if t1 >= start and t2 <= end:
            f1.write(line)
```

Comment: I should not get the data that starts or ends after 20.00 hrs

Comment: My answer only gets data in the range 08:00:00 to 20:00:00

Comment: Well this only prints True or False .. I need to separate the data to another output file. Any Way thanks for the lead.

Comment: it is a boolean test, `if t1 >= start and t2 <= end` then the line should be outputted, if False it does not fall inside the range, I added how to write the output to a file

Comment: Time wise this works fine but also the problem is in some cases the start time is in Day1 and the end time is in Day2 both in case of 8am to 8pm and yet that data is also pulled. How do we restrict those with same day and in decided time range?

Comment: then you need to parse the day also and make sure it is the same day, something like `print(t1.time() >= start and t2.time() <= end and t1.day == t2.day`